# Files different docker container export versus Docker Compose container when transpiling with Babel?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, babeljs

**Edit/Solution**

The below issue was taking place because I was mounting my local files as volumes with the volumes section of the docker-compose. This was a legacy piece of code that I didn't initially notice. Leaving this up in case someone else has a similar issue. Thanks for the help.

---

**Original Question**

My Dockerfile (below) utilizes Babel to transpile ES6+ code into NodeJS10 code before it's shipped for prod. When I run `docker container export myService...`, the file structure is exactly as I expect with my `import blah from /elsewhere` statements being transpiled to `var blah = require('elsewhere')`.

However, when I run this service locally with docker-compose and exec in with something like `docker exec -it d66e623c8695 /bin/bash`, I see the ES6+ syntax rather than transpiled code. This forces me to start my service locally with `babel-node src/index.js` when I'd much prefer to run it post-transpile with `node src/index.js`.

I haven't been able to wrap my head around why these are different, when starting my container with `docker-compose up` begins by building my container anew.

Any clarification about how this works would be greatly appreciated.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.14.1 AS base
LABEL maintainer Pat D "me@me.com"

RUN mkdir /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN mkdir /procedures
RUN mkdir ./src

COPY procedures ./procedures
COPY src ./src
COPY package.json yarn.lock .sequelizerc jest.integration.json deploy.sh Dockerrun.aws.json.template ./


# Install postgresql so we can run the migrations. -qq and piping is to keep apt-get from spamming with logs
# see https://peteris.rocks/blog/quiet-and-unattended-installation-with-apt-get/
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get -qq clean  < /dev/null > /dev/null &&\
    apt-get -qq update  < /dev/null > /dev/null &&\
    apt-get -qq install -y curl postgresql libpq-dev build-essential  < /dev/null > /dev/null &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/*


# Install dependencies
FROM base AS dependencies
RUN yarn install --quiet &&\
  yarn install --silent && \
  cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules

# Build
FROM dependencies AS build
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN rm -rf src
RUN ls
RUN mv dist src

RUN ls
RUN cat src/index.js
# this outputs transpiled code when i build in docker compose

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  pat-service:
    build:
      context: .
      target: build
    working_dir: /home/app
    command: ls src
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/app
      - /home/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3030:3000
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PGUSER: user
      PGHOST: db
      PGPASSWORD: password
      PGDATABASE: db
      PGPORT: 5432
      LOGGLY_TOKEN: logglyuuidv4
      LOGGLY_SUBDOMAIN: lsd1
      STACK_NAME: test

networks:
 default:
   external:
     name: architecture_default
```

Comment: What exactly are we trying to do here? Aside from docker. like in the easiest way possible what do you want to accomplish with docker/docker-compose

Comment: Yeah I'd like to run container with docker-compose in the same way that it's run for production. So i'd like to be able to run tests, and start up the service with regular node, rather than being forced to use babel-node, which is different behavior than what happens when i actually put it up in production. Also I'd just like to know why it behaves differently, as that will help me set up my containers more efficiently in the future.